# WPF RibbonTabHeader DataTrigger doesn´t work with ViewModel property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a Ribbon Control and this style for the tab header. Both are defined in the PartRibbonMenuView.

The Style is defined as below:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RibbonTabHeader}" x:Key="RibbonTabHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type RibbonTabHeader}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>                    
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RibbonTabHeader">
                <Border x:Name="TabHeader" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="6,6,0,0" Margin="1,0" BorderBrush="#FF707070">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0"/>
                </Border>                        
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                            
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="TabHeader" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="TabHeader" Property="Background" Value="#3D26A0DA" />
                        <Setter TargetName="TabHeader" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF1A5AAB" />
                    </Trigger>
                    
                    <Trigger Property="IsRibbonTabSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="TabHeader" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2,2,2,0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="TabHeader" Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                        <Setter TargetName="TabHeader" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF1A5AAB" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SketchIsActive}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="TabHeader" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.5,1.5,1.5,0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="TabHeader" Property="Background" Value="red" />
                        <Setter TargetName="TabHeader" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I´ve tried using the style in two ways:

```
<Ribbon TabHeaderStyle="{StaticResource RibbonTabHeader}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Background="WhiteSmoke"> ...<Ribbon/>
```

And also in the opening of the RibbonTab:

```
<RibbonTab Header="Sketch" TabIndex="1" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource RibbonTabHeader}"> ...<RibbonTab/>
```

And the property of the PartViewModel

```
public bool SketchIsActive
{
    get { return sketchIsActive; }
    set
    {
        sketchIsActive = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SketchIsActive));
    }
}
```

To make sure that the property returns True I´ve done:

```
public bool SketchIsActive
{
    get { return True; }
    set
    {
        sketchIsActive = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SketchIsActive));
    }
}
```

But still doesn´t work.

Finally the implementation of the PropertyChanged event:

```
public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

The Data Context is set by:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:HomeTabViewModel}">
            <views:HomeRibbonMenuView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:PartViewModel}">
            <views:PartRibbonMenuView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:AssemblyViewModel}">
            <views:AssemblyRibbonMenuView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

This part of the code has its own ViewModel called "MainViewModel". This MainViewModel has a property called CurrentViewModel which is used for navigation. So the PartRibbonMenuView has the DataContext of the PartViewModel.

The styles of the triggers work. However, the DataTrigger doesn't work. What's going on? How can I have another style for the RibbonTabHeader when I set the ViewModel property to True?

Comment: How do you set the `DataContext` of the `RIbbon` or its parent element?

Comment: Hi @mm8 I have edited the question to add how the DataContext of the Ribbon is set.

Comment: Where is the `SketchIsActive` defined? Did you confirm that it returns `true` at runtime? What view is the `RibbonTabHeader` in? Do you explicitly set the `DataContext` of any element somewhere? Your issue is not reproducible based on the information you have provided.

Comment: @mm8 Hi, I've edited the question again adding more information. Please let me know if you need more information. The **SketchIsActive** property is defined on the **PartViewModel**. The **RibbonTabHeader** is in the view named **PartRibbonMenuView**. I'm sure the DataContext of the PartRibbonMenuView is the PartViewModel because I have other bidings that work fine. Also, the DataContext is not defined explicitly but rather implicitly as seen at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Does `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.SketchIsActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="True">` work assuming `PartRibbonMenuView` is a `UserControl`?

Comment: @mm8 WOW! That works! Awesome... Can you explain a little bit what is the idea behind the RelativeSource part? Also, why is it necessary to have DataContext.SketchIsActive defined? Shouldn't SketchIsActive do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what the `DataContext` of your `RibbonTabHeader` really is, but this binding should work assuming `PartRibbonMenuView` is a `UserControl` that has a `PartViewModel` as its `DataContext`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.SketchIsActive,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="True">
```

Setting the `RelativeSource` property of a binding lets you bind to a property of a certain ancestor type in the visual tree. Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/relativesource-markupextension?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) for more information.